# How to efficiently determine the relative ordering of sibling elements in an HTML document with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

Put simply, I need to determine which of two sibling elements comes first in DOM order, but they may not be directly adjacent siblings.  The code I'm using currently to do this looks like this:

```
/**
 * Determine if an element comes before or after another element.
 *
 * This requires both elements to be siblings.
 *
 * @param {Element} el1 - The element to use as a reference.
 * @param {Element} el2 - The element to look for.
 * @returns {?boolean} True if el2 comes before el1, false if el1 comes before el2, undefined otherwise.
 */
function isBefore(el1, el2) {
    let tmp = el1

    while (tmp.previousElementSibling) {
        if (tmp.previousElementSibling === el2) {
            return true
        }

        tmp = tmp.previousElementSibling
    }

    tmp = el1.nextElementSibling

    while (tmp.nextElementSibling) {
        if (tmp.nextElementSibling === el2) {
            return false
        }

        tmp = tmp.nextElementSibling
    }

    return undefined
}
```

I'm wondering if there's some more efficient way to perform this check in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Why bother checking `nextElementSibling`? I mean if it's not a `previousElementSibling` then it's not "before" and you can return false...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Largely because I want to be able to catch cases where the two elements aren't siblings (if such a case comes up, it's a bug somewhere in my code).  However, that made me realize that it may be faster to get a full list of all sibling elements and reduce it to checking ordering within the NodeList, so thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [contains(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) and going up one level when you run out of siblings, here is an example:

```
function isBefore(el1, el2) {
    if (el1.contains(el2) || el2.contains(el1)) {
        return undefined; // not before or after, it's a parent child relationship.
    }

    let tmp = el1.previousElementSibling || el1.parentElement

    while (tmp) {
        if (tmp === el2 || tmp.contains(el2)) {
            return true
        }
        tmp = tmp.previousElementSibling || tmp.parentElement;
    }

    return false; // if it is not before, it must be after.
}
```